# How to copy a file from /user/maria_dev/tutorials/test.csv (HDP) to /sandbox/tutorial-files/640/nifi/input (HDF)?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-sandbox, hortonworks-dataflow

Using Hortonworks HDP 3.0.1 and HDF Sandbox on Docker Desktop

I have logged into HDP, and tried to copy a file from /user/maria_dev/tutorials/test.csv point to HDF's /sandbox/tutorial-files/640/nifi/input BUT this does not work. How do I go copying a file from HDP to HDF this way with HDFS?

Answer (score 1):

@jr134

Using NiFi, you should configure connection to HDFS and get the files from HDP to HDF via nifi/hdfs processors.   You will need to put the local HDP files into hdfs from local machine.  Next you need to get copies of hdfs config files (core-site, hdfs-site, etc) and put them on the hdf cluster with permissions for nifi user to read/access.  Once this is satisfied you need to make sure you have permissions from Nifi to HDFS by making sure nifi user has access to the files.